# How to cut off decimal in Java WITHOUT rounding?

Tags: java

I have a series of Java decimals like:

```
0.43678436287643872
0.4323424556455654
0.6575643254344554
```

I wish to cut off everything after 5 decimal places. How is this possible?

Comment: Technically, no: the act of cutting off the further decimal places *is* rounding, only you're always rounding down to 5 decimal places. See the answers below for your options.

Comment: do you want result to be a String or a number?

Comment: I want the result to be a number

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to keep things fast and simple. ;)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    double[] values = {0.43678436287643872, 0.4323424556455654, 0.6575643254344554,
            -0.43678436287643872, -0.4323424556455654, -0.6575643254344554,
            -0.6575699999999999 };

    for (double v : values) 
        System.out.println(v + " => "+roundDown5(v));
}

public static double roundDown5(double d) {
    return ((long)(d * 1e5)) / 1e5;
    //Long typecast will remove the decimals
}

// Or this. Slightly slower, but faster than creating objects. ;)
public static double roundDown5(double d) {
    return Math.floor(d * 1e5) / 1e5;
}
```

prints

```
0.43678436287643874 => 0.43678
0.4323424556455654 => 0.43234
0.6575643254344554 => 0.65756
-0.43678436287643874 => -0.43678
-0.4323424556455654 => -0.43234
-0.6575643254344554 => -0.65756
-0.6575699999999999 => -0.65756
```

Comment: This may just be the best solution! I'm just trying to find any problems with it before I accept it!

Comment: What about -0.657569, does that produce -0.65756?

Comment: In the first case, your value has to be less than ten trillion to avoid an overflow, in the second case you don't need to worry.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I dont really understand the comment "Slightly slower, but faster than creating objects" how does any object created with "(long) (d * 1e5) / 1e5" or there is some autoboxing magic i dont see? :(

Comment: @vach The last time I tested `Math.floor(x)` was slightly slower than the cast `(long) x` but that was at least 5 years ago. I imagine if you tried to JMH this today it probably isn't significantly slower.

Answer (score 19):

```
float f = 0.43678436287643872;
BigDecimal fd = new BigDecimal(f);
BigDecimal cutted = fd.setScale(5, RoundingMode.DOWN);
f = cutted.floatValue();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this round the last decimal place? OP wants to avoid that.

Comment: HALF_UP won't just cut it off: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: You may actually mean `FLOOR`.

Comment: Yes, the only problem with this is that RoundingMode/UNECCESSARY causes an error so rounding has to be chosen

Comment: Its best not to mix up `float` and `double` values.

Comment: Just a note for anyone looking at this, convert your float to a string then construct your BigDecimal with that string.

Answer (score 12):

The [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) could also be of assistance here:

```
    double d = 0.436789436287643872;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.#####");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

    double outputNum = Double.valueOf(df.format(d));
    String outpoutString = df.format(d);
```

Comment: Thanks, working fine as per my requirement

Answer (score 11):

```
Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(x).substring(0,7));
```

OR

```
Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(x).substring(0,7));
```

where `x` contains the value you want to cut such as `0.43678436287643872`

Comment: @Piskvor: My mistake. I didnt counted "0.". Edited.

Comment: @HarryJoy: Thanks for suggesting

Comment: Caveat: Works if and only if the input is between -10 and 10.

Comment: I would say, if you have neagative value, its 0-8 else it will be 0-7.
@Piskvor: i 'aint get you..

Comment: E.g. `10.123456789` becomes `10.1234`.

Comment: It can keep the whole part on the front. Maybe using 0.xx for all the numbers was a mistake in hindsight

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with regular expressions like this:

```
    double[] values = { 
            0.43678436287643872,
            0.4323424556455654,
            0.6575643254344554,
            -0.43678436287643872,
            -0.4323424556455654,
            -0.6575643254344554
    };

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(-?[0-9]+[\\.\\,][0-9]{1,5})?[0-9]*$");
    for(double number : values) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(String.valueOf(number));
        boolean matchFound = m.find();
        if (matchFound) {
            System.out.println(Double.valueOf(m.group(1)));
        }
    }
```

The pattern can be easily modified if you need to support more/less decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

To generalize Peter answer you can do:

```
public static double round(double n, int decimals) {
    return Math.floor(n * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
}
```