# Formatting a double and not rounding off

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I need to format (and *not* round off) a `double` to 2 decimal places.

I tried with:

```
String s1 = "10.126";
Double f1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".00");
System.out.println("f1"+df.format(f1));
```

Result:

```
10.13
```

But I require the output to be `10.12`

Comment: This was asked the same week here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486878/how-to-cut-off-decimal-in-java-without-rounding -- this has lot more options

Answer (score 26):

Call [`setRoundingMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode%28java.math.RoundingMode%29) to set the [`RoundingMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) appropriately:

```
String s1 = "10.126";
Double f1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".00");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN); // Note this extra step
System.out.println(df.format(f1));
```

Output

```
10.12
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..but i need to use java 1.5 ..i guess the setRoundingMode() is available in 1.6

Comment: See my answer using BigDecimal instead

Comment: Yes, I am using the current version - 1.6. It would behoove you to upgrade your version too.

Answer (score 11):

You can set the rounding mode of the formatter to **DOWN**:

```
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("10.126");
BigDecimal floored = a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);  //  == 10.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [RoundingMode.FLOOR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#FLOOR)?

```
String s1 = "10.126";
Double f1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".00");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

System.out.println("f1"+df.format(f1));
```

Comment: You mean Math.round(arg0); ??
Actually that would round it off to the closest integer.

Comment: No DecimalFormat's setRoundingMode

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is truncate a string at two decimal places, consider using just String functions as shown below:

```
String s1 = "10.1234";
String formatted = s1;
int numDecimalPlaces = 2;
int i = s1.indexOf('.');
if (i != -1 && s1.length() > i + numDecimalPlaces) {
    formatted = s1.substring(0, i + numDecimalPlaces + 1);
}
System.out.println("f1" + formatted);
```

This saves on parsing into a Double and then formatting back into a String.

Comment: Thanks man....i can use it ...but then i wanted something more compact..and also i need to do a couple of calculations on these values, so any ways there will be some amount of parsing required