# Set rounding mode in Clojure's format function

Tags: java, clojure, formatting

Is there a way to set the rounding mode in the [format](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/format) function of Clojure? What I would like to achieve is, that the number is not rounded, but "floored" (e.g. `10.126` should become `10.12` and not `10.13`).

In other words, I'm looking for something similar as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560632/formatting-a-double-and-not-rounding-off) / [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560692/3398271), that is, the Clojure equivalent of [NumberFormat.setRoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)).

Any "pure", built-in Clojure solution is fine, though it does not necessarily have to be with `format`.

Out of scope is the following, (although I'm aware they are also workable solutions):

- Using any Java classes (as I said, I'm looking for for a pure and built-in Clojure-solution)
- Converting the float to string, and back to float with the current number of decimals (I'm doing this currently, and was wondering if there is a better way).

N.B.: In case this is not possible at all with a built-in Clojure function (which I'm beginning to suspect), then a link to some documentation confirming this is also a valid answer for me.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751638/clojure-rounding-to-decimal-places (that question is about rounding, not flooring!)

Answer (score 1):

`format` uses String.format(), which uses [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), which afaict does not support any rounding mode except HALF_UP.

The DecimalFormat format supports all the rounding modes, like floor so that would be one option, although you would need to use Java interop.

Another option is the Common Lisp derived `cl-format`, however afaict cl-format also does not support specifying a rounding mode (and even allows impls to pick in Common Lisp).

And finally another option might be to round the number first before printing it. Seems like `with-precision` might be helpful with that, but I didn't manage to get it to do what I want. Really this is just tapping into BigDecimal rounding capabilities.