# How to remove scientific notation from double for longest double value

Tags: java, double

I am experiencing a problem in Double value manipulation.

Lets take,

```
Double d = new Double(123456789987654321123456789d);
System.out.println(d);
```

The output is :

```
1.2345678912345678E35
```

But I want,

```
123456789987654321123456789
```

The complete digit without any notation.

I have tried all permutation using `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger` and so and so.

**Note:** I want to populate into JSON so please don't suggest just a `print` statement.

I have already read :

- [How to Avoid Scientific Notation in Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813631/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-in-double)
- [Formatting a double and not rounding off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560632/formatting-a-double-and-not-rounding-off)

Comment: Side note: you don't need to use `new` here.

Comment: Another side note: JSON does support scientific notation for numbers.

Comment: you can omit the `Double` constructor

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate of one of the linked questions and then retracted; Because this number is of the order 2^86, the latter digits get truncated as a regular double.

Answer (score 9):

Try this [`BigDecimal::toPlainString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--):

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("123456789987654321123456789");
String result = d.toPlainString();
```

Output of d is :

```
123456789987654321123456789
```

---

To populated to JSon there are many ways, I'm not sure what you want exactly, but maybe this can help you [How to create JSON Object using String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117148/how-to-create-json-object-using-string):

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("123456789987654321123456789");

JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
myObject.put("number", d.toPlainString());
```

Comment: *Note: I want to populate into JSon so please don't suggest just a print statement*

Comment: @Lino Using that value to populate JSON varies based on which JSON library the OP is using. Since the OP didn't share any information about that we can't give him a good answer on how to add this value to a JSON object.

Comment: @BackSlash You're right. @YCF_L Maybe you could provide also a solution that takes a `double` as an argument and not a `String`. As this is probably the use case the OP's having

Comment: @YCF_L not exactly, but still useful though! I meant the way to create a Bigdecimal from double

Comment: @Lino do you have a solution maybe? I don't see where is the problem with this way

Comment: @YCF_L i mean that maybe the double is generated somehow: `double d = getDouble();` and then create from the variable `d` a `BigDecimal` instance

Comment: @BackSlash i am new to json , can you pls tell me what is 'JSON varies based on which JSON library the OP is using'?

Comment: @YCF_L yeah that is good one, but the problem is i get this value as a function return type so if i convert also it is rounded off. so i cannot use this also.  

Double d = new Double(123456789987654321123456789d);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
now again it is changed...

Comment: @MohammedRizwan about JSON you can use [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) or [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
String str = String.format("%.0f", d);
```

Note that max digits a double can hold is ~17, so 123456789987654321123456789 will rounded